# Retrieve next line in splitted text

Tags: python, text

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:    
        print(os.path.join(d, file))

        for i in xrange(0, len(files)):
            for files[i] in files:
                corpus = open(os.path.join(d, files[i]), 'rb')
                corpus = corpus.read()
#                corpus = [line.lstrip() for line in corpus.split("\n")]
                lne = []
#                print(lne)

                for line in corpus.split("\n"):

                    line = re.sub(' +', ' ', line)
                    line = line.upper()

                    lne.append(line.lstrip())
```

I tried `line2 = next(iter(line))`

But it does not produce the result I want. As I have split up the text corpus into newlines, I would expect something like next(iter(line)) to work. So what I want is to get the line of code that it loops, but also get one line after 'line'.

Comment: You need to keep a reference around to your list, you aren't doing that. You shouldn't even be creating the list, you should be getting a reference to the file handler with a context manager and then iterating over the file object directly

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try to implement it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an index to access the list.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:    
        print(os.path.join(d, file))

        for i in xrange(0, len(files)):
            for files[i] in files:
                corpus = open(os.path.join(d, files[i]), 'rb')
                corpus = corpus.read()
                lne = []
                lines = corpus.split("\n")

                for i in xrange(0, len(lines) - 1):
                    line = re.sub(' +', ' ', lines[i])
                    line = line.upper()
                    lne.append(line.lstrip())
                    line2 = lines[i+1]
```

Here `i` is a value between `0` and `number of lines - 2`. Thus in the loop you can access:

```
line  = lines[i]
line2 = lines[i + 1]
```

Comment: Awesome Jedi, may the force be with you :D. Sorry you must be getting that a lot hehe

Answer (score 1):

I start with just two files:

**one.text**

```
this + that
then now
```

and **two.text**

```
science poetry
pigs + cows
```

... in the folder `"C:\scratch\sample\two.txt"`.

The main thing I'd like to mention is the availability of a relatively new way of processing the contents of files and folders in Python, the module `pathlib`, which is documented in Chapter 11. It usually makes life easier.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> for file_name in Path('c:/scratch/sample').glob('*'):
...     with open(str(file_name)) as f:
...         result_line = []
...         for line in f.readlines():
...             result_line.append(line.strip().upper().replace(' +', ' '))
...         print (' '.join(result_line))
...         

THIS  THAT THEN NOW
SCIENCE POETRY PIGS  COWS
```

I understood you to mean that you want to replace occurrences of ' +' with just one blank, and to turn entire lines into uppercase.

I want to mention also that: (a) it's best to avoid using names like `file` that might (or might not be) special words in the Python language because using them can make debugging difficult, (b) it's a good idea to use `with` when you `open` a file because then the system arranges to close the file when you leave the scope of the `with`, and (c) the one nuisance I find with using `pathlib` is that one must use something like `str` with a result (in this case `file_name`) to turn it into a file name that `open` can use.

I hope this is useful information.